# How does foldr work?

Tags: haskell, combinators, fold

Can anybody explain how does [`foldr`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:foldr) work?

Take these examples:

```
Prelude> foldr (-) 54 [10, 11]
53
Prelude> foldr (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12, 4, 10, 6]
12.0
```

I am confused about these executions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`foldr` begins at the right-hand end of the list and combines each list entry with the accumulator value using the function you give it.  The result is the final value of the accumulator after "folding" in all the list elements.  Its type is:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

and from this you can see that the list element (of type `a`) is the first argument to the given function, and the accumulator (of type `b`) is the second.

For your first example:

```
Starting accumulator = 54
11 -   54  = -43
10 - (-43) =  53

        ^  Result from the previous line

 ^ Next list item
```

So the answer you got was 53.

The second example:

```
Starting accumulator = 54
(6  + 54) / 2 = 30
(10 + 30) / 2 = 20
(4  + 20) / 2 = 12
(12 + 12) / 2 = 12
```

So the result is 12.

Edit: I meant to add, that's for finite lists.  `foldr` can also work on infinite lists but it's best to get your head around the finite case first, I think.

Comment: Are you sure foldr can work on infinite lists?  By my understanding the brackets mean it has to evaluate the last element first.

Comment: You can implement 'map', for example, using foldr, and that will work even on infinite lists.  This works because (:) is non-strict in its second argument, or in English, because the tail of the result list can remain unevaluated as you walk along it.  There are plenty of web pages around that explain this better than I can, but as I said, it takes some effort to get your head around it.  Reconciling how foldr *behaves* and how it's *defined* is not trivial.

Comment: this is downright false. `foldr` doesn't "start from the right". it's *right-associative*. you can verify by reading the source code for the `[]` instance of `Foldable` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr

Comment: This is the most understandable answer for me, a Haskell beginner.  I don't need to understand all the theoretical and implementation details behind `foldr` yet.  I just need a simple explanation of how `foldr` gets a result.  It's okay if the explanation is over simplified.  Haskell is very different then any imperative or functional language I've learned.  I only need to learn enough about `foldr` to keep moving through the Haskell 99 problems.  As I do, my mind will put together a more complete picture of what Haskell's all about.  Thank you for keeping things as simple as they can be.

Comment: @devdanke it's not oversimplified, it's wrong. according to this answer `foldr (||) False [True, error "ERROR"]` must cause an error, but it returns `True`. no, `foldr` is defined so that `foldr (||) z [] = z` and `foldr (||) z (x:xs) = x || foldr (||) z xs` and that's it.

Answer (score 195):

The easiest way to understand foldr is to rewrite the list you're folding over without the sugar.

```
[1,2,3,4,5] => 1:(2:(3:(4:(5:[]))))
```

now what `foldr f x` does is that it replaces each `:` with `f` in infix form and `[]` with `x` and evaluates the result.

For example:

```
sum [1,2,3] = foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]

[1,2,3] === 1:(2:(3:[]))
```

so

```
sum [1,2,3] === 1+(2+(3+0)) = 6
```

Comment: Best explanation indeed. Same as how Erik Meijer describes it, i.e.,
foldr is nothing but a replacement of the base case i.e., `[]` and the `cons` operator with an accumulator and function of your choosing.

Comment: This perfectly shows how do the lists work in Church's notation in lambda calculus by the way – basically a list is an unapplied `foldr`, so the user can decide what to do with "cons" and "nil" cases

Answer (score 47):

It helps to understand the distinction between `foldr` and `foldl`. Why is `foldr` called "fold right"?

Initially I thought it was because it consumed elements from right to left. Yet both `foldr` and `foldl` consume the list from left to right.

- `foldl` *evaluates* from left to right (left-associative)
- `foldr` *evaluates* from right to left (right-associative)

We can make this distinction clear with an example that uses an operator for which associativity matters. We could use a human example, such as the operator, "eats":

```
foodChain = (human : (shark : (fish : (algae : []))))

foldl step [] foodChain
  where step eater food = eater `eats` food  -- note that "eater" is the accumulator and "food" is the element

foldl `eats` [] (human : (shark : (fish : (algae : []))))
  == foldl eats (human `eats` shark)                              (fish : (algae : []))
  == foldl eats ((human `eats` shark) `eats` fish)                (algae : [])
  == foldl eats (((human `eats` shark) `eats` fish) `eats` algae) []
  ==            (((human `eats` shark) `eats` fish) `eats` algae)
```

The semantics of this `foldl` is: A human eats some shark, and then the same human who has eaten shark then eats some fish, etc. The eater is the accumulator.

Contrast this with:

```
foldr step [] foodChain
    where step food eater = eater `eats` food.   -- note that "eater" is the element and "food" is the accumulator

foldr `eats` [] (human : (shark : (fish : (algae : []))))
  == foldr eats (human `eats` shark)                              (fish : (algae : []))))
  == foldr eats (human `eats` (shark `eats` (fish))               (algae : [])
  == foldr eats (human `eats` (shark `eats` (fish `eats` algae))) []
  ==            (human `eats` (shark `eats` (fish `eats` algae)
```

The semantics of this `foldr` is: A human eats a shark which has already eaten a fish, which has already eaten some algae. The food is the accumulator.

Both `foldl` and `foldr` "peel off" eaters from left to right, so that's not the reason we refer to foldl as "left fold". Instead, the order of evaluation matters.

Answer (score 31):

Think about `foldr`'s very [definition](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold):

```
 -- if the list is empty, the result is the initial value z
 foldr f z []     = z                  
 -- if not, apply f to the first element and the result of folding the rest 
 foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

So for example `foldr (-) 54 [10,11]` must equal `(-) 10 (foldr (-) 54 [11])`, i.e. expanding again, equal `(-) 10 ((-) 11 54)`.  So the inner operation is `11 - 54`, that is, -43; and the outer operation is `10 - (-43)`, that is, `10 + 43`, therefore `53` as you observe.  Go through similar steps for your second case, and again you'll see how the result forms!

Comment: In the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#foldr), the definition is `foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z`

Comment: @Student it changed. in the past it was like it's in this answer, and then they changed it. but the result is the same: the equations in this answer follow from today's definition.

Answer (score 23):

`foldr` means fold from the right, so `foldr (-) 0 [1, 2, 3]` produces `(1 - (2 - (3 - 0)))`.  In comparison `foldl` produces `(((0 - 1) - 2) - 3)`.

When the operators are not [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity) `foldl` and `foldr` will get different results.

In your case, the first example expands to `(10 - (11 - 54))`  which gives 53.

Answer (score 10):

An easy way to understand `foldr` is this: It replaces every list constructor with an application of the function provided. Your first example would translate to:

`10 - (11 - 54)`

from:

`10 : (11 : [])`

A good piece of advice that I got from the Haskell Wikibook might be of some use here:

> As a rule you should use `foldr` on lists that might be infinite or where the fold is building up a data structure, and `foldl'` if the list is known to be finite and comes down to a single value. `foldl` (without the tick) should rarely be used at all.

Answer (score 7):

I've always thought http://foldr.com to be a fun illustration. See the [Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1395) post.

Comment: those links seem to be dead. Any idea what happened?

Comment: It was dead when he posted the link, IIRC.

Comment: `1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(…)))))))))=∞` etc. Links work for me, but the math joke doesn't.

Comment: @WillNess That's as funny as 0.99999... = 1.

Answer (score 6):

Careful readings of -- and comparisons between -- the other answers provided here should already make this clear, but it's worth noting that the accepted answer *might* be a bit misleading to beginners. As other commenters have noted, the computation foldr performs in Haskell does not "begin at the right hand end of the list"; otherwise, `foldr` could never work on infinite lists (which it does in Haskell, under the right conditions).

The [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr) for Haskell's `foldr` function should make this clear:

```
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

Each recursive computation combines the left-most atomic list item with a recursive computation over the tail of the list, viz:

```
a\[1\] `f` (a[2] `f` (a[3] `f` ... (a[n-1] `f` a[n])  ...))
```

where `a[n]` is the initial accumulator.

Because reduction is done "lazily in Haskell," **it actually begins at the left**. This is what we mean by "lazy evaluation," and it's famously a distinguishing feature of Haskell. And it's important in understanding the operation of Haskell's `foldr`; because, in fact, `foldr` builds up **and reduces** computations *recursively from the left*, binary operators that *can* short-circuit have an opportunity to, allowing infinite lists to be reduced by `foldr` under appropriate circumstances.

It will lead to far less confusion to beginners to say rather that the `r` ("right") and `l` ("left") in `foldr` and `foldl` refer to **right associativity** and **left associativity** and either leave it at that, or try and explain the implications of Haskell's lazy evaluation mechanism.

To work through your examples, following the `foldr` source code, we build up the following expression:

```
Prelude> foldr (-) 54 [10, 11]

->

10 - [11 - 54] = 53
```

And again:

```
foldr (\x y -> (x + y) / 2) 54 [12, 4, 10, 6]

->

(12 + (4 + (10 + (6 + 54) / 2) / 2) / 2) / 2 = 12
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, your answer really lead me to understand what's going on really on `foldr` and infinite lists.

Answer (score 4):

I think that implementing map, foldl and foldr in a simple fashion helps explain how they work. Worked examples also aid in our understanding.

```
  myMap f [] = []
  myMap f (x:xs) = f x : myMap f xs

  myFoldL f i [] = i
  myFoldL f i (x:xs) = myFoldL f (f i x) xs

  > tail [1,2,3,4] ==> [2,3,4]
  > last [1,2,3,4] ==> 4
  > head [1,2,3,4] ==> 1
  > init [1,2,3,4] ==> [1,2,3]

  -- where f is a function,
  --  acc is an accumulator which is given initially
  --  l is a list.
  --
  myFoldR' f acc [] = acc
  myFoldR' f acc l = myFoldR' f (f acc (last l)) (init l)

  myFoldR f z []     = z
  myFoldR f z (x:xs) = f x (myFoldR f z xs)

  > map (\x -> x/2) [12,4,10,6] ==> [6.0,2.0,5.0,3.0]
  > myMap (\x -> x/2) [12,4,10,6] ==> [6.0,2.0,5.0,3.0]

  > foldl (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12, 4, 10, 6] ==> 10.125
  > myFoldL (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12, 4, 10, 6] ==> 10.125

    foldl from above: Starting accumulator = 54
      (12  + 54) / 2 = 33
      (4 + 33) / 2 = 18.5
      (10  + 18.5) / 2 = 14.25
      (6 + 14.25) / 2 = 10.125`

 > foldr (++) "5" ["1", "2", "3", "4"] ==> "12345"

 > foldl (++) "5" ["1", "2", "3", "4"] ==> “51234"

 > foldr (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12,4,10,6] ==> 12
 > myFoldR' (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12,4,10,6] ==> 12
 > myFoldR (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12,4,10,6] ==> 12

    foldr from above: Starting accumulator = 54
        (6  + 54) / 2 = 30
        (10 + 30) / 2 = 20
        (4  + 20) / 2 = 12
        (12 + 12) / 2 = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets look at the arguments:

- a function (that takes a list element and a value (a possible partial result) of the same kind of the value it returns);
- a specification of the initial result for the empty list special case
- a list;

return value:

- some final result

It first applies the function to the last element in the list and the empty list result. It then reapplies the function with this result and the previous element, and so forth until it takes some current result and the first element of the list to return the final result.

Fold "folds" a list around an initial result using a function that takes an element and some previous folding result. It repeats this for each element. So, foldr does this starting at the end off the list, or the right side of it.

`folr f emptyresult [1,2,3,4]` turns into
 `f(1, f(2, f(3, f(4, emptyresult) ) ) )` . Now just follow parenthesis in evaluation and that's it.

One important thing to notice is that the supplied function `f` must handle its own return value as its second argument which implies both must have the same type.

Source: [my post](http://yaitguy.blogspot.ie/2013/04/a-foldr-in-javascript.html) where I look at it from an imperative uncurried javascript perspective if you think it might help.

Answer (score 0):

The images in this wiki page visualize the idea of `foldr` (and `foldl` also):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29

For example, the result of `foldr (-) 0 [1,2,3]` is 2. It can be visualized as:

```
  -
 / \
1   -
   / \
  2   -
     / \
    3   0
```

That is (from bottom to the top):

```
1 - ( -1 )      = 2
    2 - ( 3 )
        3 - 0
```

So `foldr (\x y -> (x+y)/2) 54 [12, 4, 10, 6]` is being computed through:

```
12 `f` (12.0)          = 12.0
     4 `f` (20.0)
        10 `f` (30.0)
             6 `f` 54
```