# Haskell List Duplicates (if possible with map, elem and foldr)

Tags: haskell

My Task is to take in Data and "filter" out every duplicate like in the example down below. If possible, I have to use the functions map, elem and foldr
I honestly don't know how to do it, if anyone can give me a hint on how to solve the problem, I'd be grateful.

```
type StudentName = String
type CourseName  = String
type ExamScore   = (CourseName, Float)
type StudentData = [(StudentName, [ExamScore])]

students :: StudentData
students = [
 ("Tim Berners-Lee", [("Maths", 1.3), ("Algorithm", 2.0)]), 
 ("Ada Lovelace",[("Info 1", 3.0), ("Lambda-Maths", 1.7), ("Science", 2.3), ("Data Mining", 2.7)]),
 ("Alan Turing", [("Maths", 1.7), ("operatingSystems", 2.0), ("Lambda-Maths", 1.7)]),
 ("Alonzo Church", [("Info 2", 2.7), ("Systems", 2.3), ("Lambda-Maths", 1.0), ("Algorithm", 3.0)]),
 ("Bjarne Stroustrup", [("Info 1", 2.7), ("Info 2", 1.3), ("operatingSystems", 2.0), ("Topology", 2.3)]),("Bjarne Stroustrup", [("Info 1", 2.7), ("Info 2", 1.3), ("operatingSystems", 2.0), ("Topology", 2.3)]),
 ("Donald E. Knuth", [("Maths", 3.3), ("Info 2", 1.7), ("Lambda-Maths", 2.0), ("Science", 4.0)]),
 ("Grace Hopper", [("Info 3", 1.0), ("operatingSystems", 2.3), ("Systems", 1.7)]),
 ("Annie Easley", [("Maths", 1.0), ("Info 2", 1.7)]),
 ("Edsger W. Dijkstra", [("Topology", 3.3), ("Algorithm", 2.7), ("Systems", 4.0)]),
 ("John von Neumann", [("Maths", 3.3), ("Algoritmische Topologie", 1.0), ("operatingSystems", 1.3), ("Systems", 5.3)])
 ]

courses :: [CourseName]
courses = ["Maths", "Info 1", "Info 2", "Algorithm", "operatingSystems", "Topology", "Lambda-Maths", "Systems", "Science", "Data Mining"]

examResults :: [ExamScore]
examResults = [("Maths", 3.3), ("Topology", 1.0), ("operatingSystems", 1.3), ("Systems", 5.3), ("Info 1", 1.7), ("Info 2", 1.7), ("Data Mining", 0.3)]





filterDuplicates :: StudentData -> StudentData
filterDuplicates



--e.g.
-- filterDuplicates [("Tom", [("Course A", 1.3), ("Course B", 2.0)]), ("Tom", [("Course A", 1.3), ("Course B", 2.0)])]
-- output: [("Tom", [("Course A", 1.3), ("Course B", 2.0)])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can solve this problem, you need to have a good understanding of the functions `elem`, `map` and `foldr`. (Edit: maybe you won't need `filter`. I originally read `foldr` as `filter`, but there are some useful details in that section that will help so I left it.

### elem

If you have some prior programming experience, `elem` should not be hard. When learning new functions in Haskell, we usually start with the type signature because it can give us a lot of information. For `elem` it is `a -> [a] -> Bool`. This means it takes two parameters, a value of type `a` and a list of values of type `a`, then it returns a `Bool`. If the value is in the list than it returns `True` otherwise it returns `False`.

```hs
> elem 1 [1,2,3]
True
> elem "car" ["boat","bus","airplane"]
False
```

In a lot of Haskell code you will probably see `elem` used in infix style by wrapping it in backticks.

```hs
> 1 `elem` [1,2,3]
True
> "car" `elem` ["boat","bus","airplane"]
False
```

### filter

Again we will start with the type signature. For `filter` it is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. `filter` takes two parameters, `(a -> Bool)` is a function `f` that takes one parameter of type `a` and returns a `Bool`, and `[a]` is a list of values of type `a`. It will evaluate function `f` on each value on the list. When `f` returns `False` it will ignore that item, when `f` returns `True`, it will collect it and add it to a new list that it returns. Here some examples.

```hs
> even [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[2,4,6]
> odd [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,3,5]
```

Before we go any further it will be helpful to understand what lambda functions are (also called anonymous functions). They are a way to define a function without giving a name to the function. It also let's us define a function in line. The syntax looks like this `(\x -> ...)` where `x` is the name of the parameter we pass in and `...` should be replaced with a function body. Now let's try to define some lambda functions for `filter` (remember that they have to return `Bool`).

```hs
-- keep numbers greater than zero
> filter (\x -> x > 0) [-1,-2,3,5,0,-4,100] 
[3,5,100]
-- keep lists (Strings) longer than 3
> filter (\x -> length x > 3) ["the", "a", "hello", "goodnight", "bye"]
["hello", "goodnight"]
```

### map

Finally `map` has a type signature that looks like this `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. `(a -> b)` is a function `f` that takes a value of type `a` and returns a value of type `b`, `[a]` is a list of values of types `a`, then it returns `[b]` which is a list of values of type `[b]`. It evaluates the function `f` on each value in the list and returns a list with the same number of elements, but the values might be altered. Here are a few examples.

```hs
-- here type a is Int and type b is also Int
-- add one to every element in the list
> map (\x -> x + 1) [1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]

-- here type a is String and type b is also String
-- append a "." to every String in the list
> map (\x -> x ++ ".") ["hello", "goodbye"]
["hello.", "goodbye."]

-- here type a is String and type b is Int
> map (\x -> length x) ["hello", "goodbye"]

-- here type a is Int and type b is String
> map (\x -> show x) [1,2,3,4]
["1","2","3","4"]
```

### foldr

`foldr` is a bit more complicated. Its type signature for a list is 
`(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. After you are comfortable with `map`, I would
take a look at this [Stack Overlow question on foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757740/how-does-foldr-work).

### pattern matching

You may also need to understand also understand pattern matching on tuples.
[Haskell Pattern Matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching).